# Pivot Repeated fields in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

My Schema looks something like this:

```
userid:string
timestamp:integer
params:nested/repeated field with 2 fields
  - name:string (possible values: "a", "b","c")
  - value:string
```

I want my query to return the following:

```
userid, timestamp, a, b, c
123, 1447799796, foo, bar, xyz
233, 1447799900, bob, xxx, yyy
:
:
```

What's the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when possible values are known in advance and there are not that many of them to write manually SQL - you can use below:

```
SELECT 
  userid,
  ts,
  MAX(IF(params.name = "a", params.value, NULL)) WITHIN RECORD a,
  MAX(IF(params.name = "b", params.value, NULL)) WITHIN RECORD b,
  MAX(IF(params.name = "c", params.value, NULL)) WITHIN RECORD c
FROM yourTable
```

If possible values are "unknown" in advance and/or dynamic from run to run, you can use below helper SQL to generate  above type of SQL.

```
SELECT 'select userid, ts, ' + 
   GROUP_CONCAT_UNQUOTED(
      'max(if(params.name = "' + STRING(params.name) + '", params.value, null)) 
       WITHIN RECORD as [' + STRING(params.name) + ']'
   ) 
   + ' from yourTable '
FROM (SELECT params.name FROM yourTable GROUP BY params.name)
```

Comment: Thanks Mike, what about using the SQL standard version of BigQuery ?

Comment: @FlorentCailly - Good question! A lot has changed since Nov 2015. Standard SQL of BigQuery is highly recommended nowadays! I migrated here long ago :) with exception of when I need to use snapshots (which are still available in Legacy SQL Only)

Comment: Thanks Mike, could you post an update on how to do this using standard SQL ? For some reason, when I use the methodology above and then aggregate, I am not getting the correct result. If I use `FIRST` instead of `MAX`, I am getting a result much closer but still not the correct result.

Here is the query:

Comment: if you can post new question with your specifics - i will be more than happy to answer :o)

Comment: Thanks Mike, I just did: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45642206/big-query-pivot-and-aggregate-repeated-fields

Answer (score 1):

Something along these lines:

```
SELECT 
  userid,
  timestamp,
  FIRST(name == "a", value, NULL) WITHIN RECORD a,
  FIRST(name == "b", value, NULL) WITHIN RECORD b,
  FIRST(name == "c", value, NULL) WITHIN RECORD c,
FROM t
```