# BigQuery product level custom dimensions

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to query basic productlevel dimension from GA in combination with custom dimensions at the product level and I can't get it to work:(
Any help and/or suggestions are more than welcome! (current query is below)

```html
SELECT
  date,
  hits.product.v2ProductName AS productName,
  hits.product.productSKU AS SKU,
  MAX(IF(hits.product.customDimensions.index=126,hits.product.customDimensions.value, null)) WITHIN hits AS customDimesion126,
  COUNT(hits.transaction.transactionId)
FROM
  TABLE_DATE_RANGE([XXX.ga_sessions_],TIMESTAMP('2016-10-16'), TIMESTAMP('2016-10-16'))

WHERE
  hits.transaction.transactionId IS NOT NULL
  
GROUP BY
  date,
  productName,
  SKU
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: @Nebi, Invalid mixture of scoped and unscoped aggregation functions

Comment: Have you seen this past question? You may be able to adapt the answer to your needs: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39998428/select-several-event-params-in-a-single-row-for-firebase-events-stored-in-google/40000034. I will see if I can come up with a query as well.

Comment: @ElliottBrossard, no i did not see that one, thanks! but i tried a few changes based on that suggestion did not work either.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have access to a table with quite the same schema to be able to try this out, but does something like this query work? You'll need to enable [standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/) to run it (uncheck "Use Legacy SQL" under "Show Options"):

```
SELECT
  date,
  hits.product.v2ProductName AS productName,
  hits.product.productSKU AS SKU,
  (SELECT value
   FROM UNNEST(hits.product.customDimensions)
   WHERE index=126) AS customDimension126,
  COUNT(*)
FROM
  `your-dataset.ga_sessions_*` t, t.hits hits
WHERE
  _PARTITION_TIME = '2016-10-16' AND
  hits.transaction.transactionId IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY
  date,
  productName,
  SKU;
```

Answer (score 0):

Same here  - I don't have access to a table with quite the same schema to be able to try this out - so below is shot in the air :o)

For BigQuery Legacy SQL - as I wanted to preserve your original query as much as possible

```
SELECT
  DATE,
  productName,
  SKU,
  customDimesion126,
  SUM(cnt) AS transactions
FROM (
  SELECT
    DATE,
    hits.product.v2ProductName AS productName,
    hits.product.productSKU AS SKU,
    MAX(IF(hits.product.customDimensions.index=126,hits.product.customDimensions.value, NULL)) WITHIN hits AS customDimesion126,
    COUNT(hits.transaction.transactionId) WITHIN hits AS cnt
  FROM
    TABLE_DATE_RANGE([XXX.ga_sessions_],TIMESTAMP('2016-10-16'), TIMESTAMP('2016-10-16'))
  WHERE
    hits.transaction.transactionId IS NOT NULL
)  
GROUP BY
  DATE,
  productName,
  SKU,
  customDimesion126
```