# Big Query pivot and aggregate repeated fields

Tags: google-bigquery

I would like to pivot the fields 'unitId', 'firebase_screen_class' so that each one appears in a separate column:

```
SELECT
  event.name,
  event_param.value.string_value AS ad_unit,
  COUNT(*) AS event_count
FROM
  `app_events_20170510`, 
  UNNEST(event_dim) AS event, 
  UNNEST(event.params) as event_param
WHERE
  event.name in ('Ad_requested', 'Ad_clicked', 'Ad_shown')
  and event_param.key in ('unitId', 'screen_class')
GROUP BY 1,2
```

I have used the following query using legacy SQL but it is not showing the correct aggregation results:

```
SELECT event_name, ad_unit, count(*) FROM
(
SELECT
  event_dim.name as event_name,
  MAX(IF(event_dim.params.key = "firebase_screen_class", event_dim.params.value.string_value, NULL)) WITHIN RECORD as firebase_screen_class,
  MAX(IF(event_dim.params.key = "unitId", event_dim.params.value.string_value, NULL)) WITHIN RECORD as ad_unit
FROM
  [app_events_20170510]
WHERE
  event_dim.name in ('Ad_requested','Ad_shown', 'Ad_clicked')
  and event_dim.params.key in ('unitId','screen_class')
)
group by 1,2
```

I am looking for the following output:

```
_________________________________________________________________________
| event_dim.name   | unitId         | screen_class         | count_events|
|__________________|________________|______________________|_____________|
| Ad_requested     | hpg            | socialFeed           |    520      |
|__________________|________________|______________________|_____________|
| Ad_shown         | hpg            | chat                 |    950      |
|__________________|________________|______________________|_____________|
| Ad_requested     | hni            | chat                 |    740      |
|__________________|________________|______________________|_____________|
```

All events `Ad_requested`, `Ad_shown` and `Ad_clicked` have parameters with the same keys(`unitId`, `screen_class`) and also the same values for each key (`unitId`: `hpg`, `hni` / `screen_class`: `socialFeed`, `chat`)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select several event params in a single row for Firebase events stored in Google BigQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39998428/select-several-event-params-in-a-single-row-for-firebase-events-stored-in-google)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `aggregation` AS (
  SELECT
    event.name,
    event_param.key,
    COUNT(*) AS event_count
  FROM
    `app_events_20170510`, 
    UNNEST(event_dim) AS event, 
    UNNEST(event.params) AS event_param
  WHERE
    event.name IN ('Ad_requested', 'Ad_clicked', 'Ad_shown')
    AND event_param.key IN ('unitId', 'firebase_screen_class','house')
  GROUP BY 1, 2
)
SELECT 
  name,
  MAX(IF(key = 'unitId', event_count, NULL)) AS unitId,
  MAX(IF(key = 'firebase_screen_class', event_count, NULL)) AS firebase_screen_class,
  MAX(IF(key = 'house', event_count, NULL)) AS house
FROM `aggregation`
GROUP BY name
```

> Update based on clarifications in comments:

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT
  event.name,
  (SELECT value.string_value FROM UNNEST(event.params) WHERE key = 'unitId') AS unitId,
  (SELECT value.string_value FROM UNNEST(event.params) WHERE key = 'firebase_screen_class') AS firebase_screen_class,
  (SELECT value.string_value FROM UNNEST(event.params) WHERE key = 'house') AS house,
  COUNT(1) AS event_count
FROM `app_events_20170510`, UNNEST(event_dim) AS event
WHERE event.name IN ('Ad_requested', 'Ad_clicked', 'Ad_shown')
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4
```

> ... *Out of curiosity, I tried to replicate the query using legacy SQL* ... -
>
> Added version for BigQuery Legacy SQL (*purely for learning purposes and in hope to help those who consider migrating to Standard SQL as two versions of same task is now presented here*)

```sql
#legacySQL
SELECT name, product_id, source, firebase_event_origin, COUNT(1) AS event_count
FROM (
  SELECT event_dim.name AS name,
    MAX(IF(event_dim.params.key = 'unitId', event_dim.params.value.string_value, NULL)) WITHIN RECORD AS unitId,
    MAX(IF(event_dim.params.key = 'firebase_screen_class', event_dim.params.value.string_value, NULL)) WITHIN RECORD AS firebase_screen_class,
    MAX(IF(event_dim.params.key = 'house', event_dim.params.value.string_value, NULL)) WITHIN RECORD AS house,
  FROM FLATTEN([project:dataset.app_events_20170510], event_dim) AS event
  WHERE event_dim.name IN ('Ad_requested', 'Ad_clicked', 'Ad_shown')
)
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3, 4
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I ran the query but it is not what I am trying to achieve.  

I am looking for:  
`event_name | unitId.values | house.values | firebase_screen_class.values| count_event`

Comment: i see now what you mean

Comment: yes, sorry. I accidentally posted my comment before finishing it :-)

Comment: i just realized  - i don't know what you mean by xxx.values. is it list of string_values for respective key or something else. I think yo should provide  more details/example of output!

Comment: I have added more details, please let me know if it is not clear. Thanks !

Comment: in my mind  - this still can be read in quite multiple ways. what is the logic of grouping in one line? for example you have two lines for `Ad_requested` - what was the logic of getting those?

Comment: For the `Ad_requested` event, I want to know how many events exist for each combination of the parameters values for these event. There is two lines for `Ad_requested` because each line has different values for the parameters `screen_class` and `unitId`

Comment: Thanks Mike, just saw your update. 
There is an issue with it, it does not show the combination of the parameters. See screenshot here: [link](http://screencast.com/t/Ro7JR8BHYQ).
 On each row, only one of the 3 parameters have a value
the other two parameters show null.

Comment: most likely not  - will check one more time  when get a min :)

Comment: ok thanks, what I mean is that each event have 3 parameters that is recorded per event. I want to see for each event, the event name and the value for each of the 3 parameters on the same row. I have added comments to the screenshot to explain [link](https://www.screencast.com/t/Et5xeGeXr)

Comment: glad we did it finally :o)

Comment: Out of curiosity, I tried to replicate the query using legacy SQL. I used the following construct: `MAX(IF(event_dim.params.key = "unitId", event_dim.params.string_value, NULL)) WITHIN RECORD productID` but it does not provide the correct aggregation result. Is this query also doable with legacy SQL ?

Comment: see addition in my answer

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant thanks for this great answer! How do I use the FROM with `UNNEST(event_dim)` when I have two datasets (`IOS.app_events_20171106` and `ANDROID.app_events_20171106`)?

Comment: @DorianRoy - try replacing \`app_events_20170510` with (SELECT <needed fields> FROM \`IOS.app_events_20171106\` UNION ALL SELECT <needed fields> FROM \`ANDROID.app_events_20171106\`)