# create new columns from row in Bigquery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, pivot-table

I have a table like below that presents the carts of products

[image]

every id has different products, example: id 1 has 3 products, id 2 has 4...but the maximum products for each id is 10.  the timestamp is sorted in DESC. so now I'd like to transform this table like this:

[image]

the schema of table:

[image]

I tried the solution here [Pivot Repeated fields in BigQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33768448/pivot-repeated-fields-in-bigquery/33769831#33769831) but the number of columns are too many. How can I have new columns corresponds with maximum 10 products

thank you

Comment: please clarify schema of the table. are those three fields independent columns or they "belong" to repeated record? show real schema to avoid confusion

Comment: got it :o) I recommend adding such info into your question rather than within the comments :o) so it is better viewed for the rest

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant yes, you're right :)) I just edited my question.

Comment: thanks @MikhailBerlyant .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Below options are for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT id, 
  products[SAFE_OFFSET(0)].product_id product_id_1,
  products[SAFE_OFFSET(0)].price price_1,
  products[SAFE_OFFSET(1)].product_id product_id_2,
  products[SAFE_OFFSET(1)].price price_2,
  products[SAFE_OFFSET(2)].product_id product_id_3,
  products[SAFE_OFFSET(2)].price price_3,
  products[SAFE_OFFSET(3)].product_id product_id_4,
  products[SAFE_OFFSET(3)].price price_4,
  products[SAFE_OFFSET(4)].product_id product_id_5,
  products[SAFE_OFFSET(4)].price price_5,
  products[SAFE_OFFSET(5)].product_id product_id_6,
  products[SAFE_OFFSET(5)].price price_6,
  products[SAFE_OFFSET(6)].product_id product_id_7,
  products[SAFE_OFFSET(6)].price price_7,
  products[SAFE_OFFSET(7)].product_id product_id_8,
  products[SAFE_OFFSET(7)].price price_8,
  products[SAFE_OFFSET(8)].product_id product_id_9,
  products[SAFE_OFFSET(8)].price price_9,
  products[SAFE_OFFSET(9)].product_id product_id_10,
  products[SAFE_OFFSET(9)].price price_10
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

or

```
#standardSQL
SELECT id, 
  MAX(IF(off = 0, product_id, NULL)) product_id_1,
  MAX(IF(off = 0, price, NULL)) price_1,
  MAX(IF(off = 1, product_id, NULL)) product_id_2,
  MAX(IF(off = 1, price, NULL)) price_2,
  MAX(IF(off = 2, product_id, NULL)) product_id_3,
  MAX(IF(off = 2, price, NULL)) price_3,
  MAX(IF(off = 3, product_id, NULL)) product_id_4,
  MAX(IF(off = 3, price, NULL)) price_4,
  MAX(IF(off = 4, product_id, NULL)) product_id_5,
  MAX(IF(off = 4, price, NULL)) price_5,
  MAX(IF(off = 5, product_id, NULL)) product_id_6,
  MAX(IF(off = 5, price, NULL)) price_6,
  MAX(IF(off = 6, product_id, NULL)) product_id_7,
  MAX(IF(off = 6, price, NULL)) price_7,
  MAX(IF(off = 7, product_id, NULL)) product_id_8,
  MAX(IF(off = 7, price, NULL)) price_8,
  MAX(IF(off = 8, product_id, NULL)) product_id_9,
  MAX(IF(off = 8, price, NULL)) price_9,
  MAX(IF(off = 9, product_id, NULL)) product_id_10,
  MAX(IF(off = 9, price, NULL)) price_10
FROM `project.dataset.table`,
UNNEST(products) product WITH OFFSET off
GROUP BY id
```